Bootstrapping as an alternative to simulation-based power/sample size calculations
Typically when one has to do a sample size and/or calculation, they might use simple sample size calculations from textbooks or use gpower. However, there are only closed form calculations for very basic procedures. For complex analyses, it will require the user to simulate data to compute estimated power/sample sizes. The problem with simulating data is getting the right information to make the simulation realistic. You're going to have to obtain estimates for the slopes, the intercept, standard errors, etc. Also, if you're off in your estimate of these things, it makes your sample size calculation wrong. This is a daunting task.
Now, suppose one has pilot data. It seems to me that, instead of guessing at slopes/intercept/standard errors, one could instead bootstrap from the pilot data as an alternative for the purpose of computing power/sample size. Has this been done before? If not, is there a reason this is a bad idea?
Of course, there is the obvious problems that arise if the pilot data are not representative of the population, though I suppose that might be overcome through some sort of an MCMC procedure.
Edit: I had one major oversight. Using this procedure wouldn't allow you to compute power because you don't know that actual population value. So maybe I'll modify my question to ask the ideal way to use pilot data to do sample size calculations?

I'm not sure what you mean by "bootstrap from the pilot data" unless it simply refers to "use what we know to guess what might happen."  That, after all, is what one always does in power analyses and, as you put it well, the issue concerns making reasonable assumptions.  But if you mean "bootstrap" in the usual statistical meaning (as a kind of procedure), please elaborate on how you suppose that would be carried out.

Sure. Say I have pilot data of 100 participants. What I mean is that we might draw 100 bootstrapped samples with a sample size of 100, then another 100 bootstrapped samples with a sample size of 200, then 300, etc. From that we can calculate average p-values for each sample size. Though, having said that, I realize there's no way to calculate power because you don't actually know the population values.

I could see that procedure working, but only if you are contemplating a sample size of 100.  Samples of size 200, 300 etc. are not bootstrap samples at all: you seem instead to be describing a simulation based on the properties of an existing dataset. There's nothing the matter with that, provided you pay attention to what it means and are aware of its potential limitations.

It should be noted that sample size calculations based on parameters estimated from a sample (but treating them as if they were the actual population value) will tend to underestimate power (for similar reasons that using a z-test when replacing $\sigma$ by $s$ will underestimate the uncertainty in the t-value). Pilot samples are often small, so the impact of this on the actual power may be nontrivial. It's possible to account for this, but from what I have seen when people use pilot samples to choose sample size the effect is often neglected.

"So maybe I'll modify my question to ask the ideal way to use pilot data to do sample size calculations?". You might find this other thread interesting: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/343926/power-calculations-using-pilot-effect-sizes
